# HSPICE Circuit Size Limitations

Tags: hspice

I want to run big circuits by HSPICE. Does HSPICE have any limitations? (for example on number of nodes)

Comment: This question should probably be addressed to the makers of HSPICE (I believe that is Synopsys).

Comment: Your probably going to be limited on physical resources before you reach the limits of spice. IE memory, cpu time

Comment: @mkeith I know they would be the best to ask, but could not find a recently active blog for them.

Comment: @laptop2d I use "top" command in unix, it does use a lot of memory or cpu.